# how to refer to the current struct in an overloaded operator?

Tags: c++, struct, operators, operator-overloading

I have a struct for which i want to define a relative order by defining < , > , <= and >= operators. actually in my order there won't be any equality, so if one struct is not smaller than another, it's automatically larger.

I defined the first operator like this:

```
struct MyStruct{
...
...

bool operator < (const MyStruct &b) const {return (somefancycomputation);}

};
```

now i'd like to define the other operators based on this operator, such that <= will return the same as < and the other two will simply return the oposite.
so for example for the > operator i'd like to write something like

```
bool operator > (const MyStruct &b) const {return !(self<b);}
```

but i don't know how to refere to this 'self' since i can refere only to the fields inside the current struct.

whole is in C++

hope my question was understandable :)

thank you for the help!

Comment: Are you sure that you want `<=` to return the same as `<` ?  I'd usually recommend against it. Having `a <= b` identically equal to `!(b < a)` and having `a > b` identically equal to `b < a` would give a more consistent set of comparisons.

Comment: Usually, one define binary operators as free functions and not as members.  This allows to get the same behavior for both arguments when implicit conversions comes into play; having implicit conversions on the second but not on the first is perturbing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Self is `*this`.

That is, `this` is a pointer to the current object, so you need to dereference it to get the actual object.

Comment: @genesys Expanding on Dave's point, You'll want to write your code as something like  "bool operator > (const MyStruct &b) const {return !((*this)<b);}"

Comment: Upvoted. Another possibility is to make a function that compares two given structs A and B.

Answer (score 6):

If you are providing an `operator<` with all the appropriate logic then (whether or not it is implemented as a free function) you can implement the other operators in terms of it as free functions. This follows the rule of preferring non-members over members where possible and free functions will have identical behaviour w.r.t. conversions of the left and right operands, whereas operators implemented as member functions don't.

e.g.

```
inline bool operator>(const MyStruct& a, const MyStruct&b)
{
    return b < a;
}

inline bool operator<=(const MyStruct& a, const MyStruct&b)
{
    return !(b < a);
}

inline bool operator>=(const MyStruct& a, const MyStruct&b)
{
    return !(a < b);
}
```

Comment: Another posting I'd like to have 10 votes to give to... And I'd like to add that `operator<`, being a binary operator that treats both of its arguments the same (it leaves them alone), usually should be implemented as a non-member, too.

Comment: thank you for your answer..
I'm sorry for the noob question, but could you also explain me what exaclty is the difference of non-members and members and why to prefere the first one?? thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This is meant as a slight improvement over [Element's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288179/how-to-refer-to-the-current-struct-in-an-overloaded-operator/1288827#1288827):

```
template< class Derived >
class Comparable {
  public:
    bool operator !=(const Derived& rhs) const
    {return !( static_cast<Derived&>(*this) == rhs ); }

    bool operator <(const Derived& rhs) const
    {return rhs < static_cast<Derived&>(*this); } 

    bool operator >=(const Derived& rhs) const
    {return !( static_cast<Derived&>(*this) < rhs ); }

    bool operator <=(const Derived& rhs) const
    {return !( static_cast<Derived&>(*this) > rhs ); }
};

struct MyStruct : public Comparable<MyStruct> {
    bool operator ==(const MyStruct & rhs) const
    {return /* whatever */; }

    bool operator <(const MyStruct & rhs) const
    {return /* whatever */; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Overloaded operator is just a member function though with a fancy syntax.
You can explicitly call it like this:

```
this->operator<( b );
```

or save yourself some hair :) and just provide `int compare( const MyStruct& )` member function and use that in all the non-member comparison operators.

Comment: Yes, providing a named function and reusing it is a much more readable approach.

Answer (score 1):

this is a pointer to your current object. So (as @Dave Hinton says) you'd have to dereference it. But, theres another option

Two options:

```
return !(*this<b)

or

return (!this->operator<(b))
```

Yes, the first one is quite nicer.

Answer (score 1):

> actually in my order there won't be any equality, so if one struct is not smaller than another, it's automatically larger.

That's a problem. C++ operations (and many algorithms) require a [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html), which (among others) implies that `x == x` holds for any `x`. More generally:

```
not (x < y) and not (y < x)
```

implies

```
x == y
```

for any `x` and `y`. In other words: you most probably *must* define some kind of equality for your struct to work with any conventional algorithm.

Comment: Lots of things will still work, though, with some provisos. `std::sort` will work, although naturally you have no control of the orders of "equivalent" values. You can still have `set` and `map`, but natutally, once you have a value a collection you can't place an "equivalent" entry in the collection (but you could with `multiset` and `multimap`). Things like `find` and `equal_range` are doomed.

Comment: A string *weak* ordering, doesn't imply a total order, or equivalence (w.r.t the order) doesn't imply equality., or in other words, `not (x < y) and not (y < x)` does not necessarily imply that `x == y`. It must hold that `not (x < x)`, though.

Comment: @Charles, doesn't "weak" mean that two elements may be equivalent with regard to the ordering? I think what you talked about is called "partial ordering" not "weak ordering" ?

Comment: IIRC, partial orderings are `<=` relationships where `a <= b && b <= a` implies `a = b`. So I wasn't talking about those. You can have `¬(a <= b)` and `¬(b <= a)` for some `a`, `b` in a partial order. In a strict weak order, I thought that strict meant `¬(a < a)` for all `a` and weak meant there exist `a`, `b` s.t. `¬(a = b) ^ ¬(a < b) ^ ¬(b < a)`. But I think that my emphasis may be wrong and you can't really separate the strict and the weak. If `<` is a strict weak ordering then `<=` (the inverse of its complement) is a total preorder but only a total order if it is also a partial order.

Comment: I think that partial orders partition sets into chains which could be extended to a full order if you linked them end to end in some arbitrary fashion, and strict weak orders (or total preorders) partition sets into a chain of equivalence sets which could be extended to a total order if you imposed an arbitrary order on each equivalence set.

Comment: @Charles: no, you can use boolean algebra to derive my statement from the rules of antisymmetry and reflexivity, which define a strict weak ordering.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `==` then? `¬(x < y) ^ ¬(y < x)` must be an equivalence relationship in a strict weak ordering, but that doesn't imply that `x` and `y` are the same element. A strict weak ordering is irreflexive, not reflexive. I think we may be using different definitions for something important.

Comment: @Charles: oops, I actually meant *irreflexivity* in my previous comment, not *reflexivity*. By `==` I mean the equivalence relation, not identity. Perhaps that's where our confusion stems from. But as I see it, (almost?) all programming languages differentiate between equality (= equivalence) and identity (= same memory location, pointer equality …).

Comment: I think so. The point that I was trying to make was that `operator==` is not used by `set`, `map`, `sort`, etc. so it does not matter if it is the same as `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` (which must be an equivalence relation for a strict weak ordering) or something more strict (an equality of values). E.g. a `struct` type containing a single double is at liberty to define `<` as (e.g.) `{ return floor(a) < floor(b); }` and reserve `==` for equality of doubles. It can still be used in standard algorithms requiring an appropriate `less` comparison.

Comment: @Charles: point taken and comment worth making. However, I mainly objected to this part of the quote: “if one struct is not smaller than another, it's automatically larger” which may result in surprises for the OP. Or it might not, depending on usage.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Tom/Dave above in that the direct way to write this:

```
return !(*this<b);
```

but for me the most explicitly clear form is:

```
return !operator<(b);
```

and Tom's: return !(this->operator<(b)); seems a little silly.

This little bit nasty C preprocessor code (I also have a better but more technical template solution):

```
#define CREATE_SYMETRIC_ORDINAL_OPERATORS(Type) \
int operator !=(Type X) {return !((*this)==X); } \
int operator <(Type X) {return !((*this)>=X); } \
int operator >=(Type X) {return (((*this)>X)||((*this)==X)); } \
int operator <=(Type X) {return (((*this)<X)||((*this)==X)); }
```

automatically defines all comparison operators assuming == and > are defined like so:

```
class Comparable {
  public:
    int operator ==(Comparable B);
    int operator >(Comparable B);
    CREATE_SYMETRIC_OPERATORS(Comparable);
};
```

Comment: That set of macros gives me the squicks a bit I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah I never liked it either and have been replacing it with a simple inheritance from a class that has == and < defined as pure virtual. Performance is a bit weaker but the readability is better

Comment: @Elemental: You can get both (simplicity and speed) by using the CRTP. Also, it's probably better to base comparison on `operator<()` as this is the one that's usually (`std::map`, `std::sort` etc.) required. Finally, IMO it's better to take the RHS argument per const reference, as the optimizer might fail to prevent the copying of an expensive to copy type. Since this is too big for a comment, I'm going to add my own answer showing this.

Comment: @Elemental: Oh, and comparison should return `bool`, not `int`!

Comment: Yep - your template solution is excellent and the RHS const & is an important improvement.

Comment: @Elemental: Up to now it missed a few `const`, though -- as does yours. `:)` Well, I'm not convinced by the idea anyway. First, for the reason given by AProgrammer I strongly prefer those operators as free functions. Second, the machinery driving this is complex enough to probably produce quite funny error messages if you do something wrong, while it only saves writing four small and dumb inline functions -- at least according to my coding style that's four lines of code.